# VS 2010 not working and Installing Visual Studio 2010 SP1 update in Windows 10

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, windows-10

I have already installed Visual Studio 2010 Professional in my system. I'm using a 64-bit system with Windows 10 Home. But when i open VS 2010 it shows the following,

[image]

Then i downloaded the VS 2010 SP1 update from this link [Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1 (Installer)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23691)

I run this program and it said it will download a total of 539 MB but then it shows the following error while downloading,

[image]

Then i tried to download the update from this link [Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1 (KB2736182)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34677)

It shows the following error,

[image]

i really want to make this work, VS 2010..Please help me out..

Comment: Rebooting might help. An installation can stop other installations unit a reboot.

Comment: Yes i tried that but it wont work

Answer (score 10):

Please see [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=18QM3gqYaGA).

Or just download the [service pack](http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/3/0/230C4F4A-2D3C-4D3B-B991-2A9133904E35/VS10sp1-KB983509.exe).